# Discord.js - Send a message when a channel is deleted

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Just wondering if it's possible to send a user a dm with a bot when a channel is deleted.

Comment: It is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, using client events. This question is quite vague and non-code specific so you should head to the Discord.JS discord server for questions like this (avail. on their website).

Comment: Okay, I'll go in more detail. I have made a ticket system with a create and a close command. If you did message.author.send('test') inside the create command and if you did it inside the close command it will send the user who closed the ticket the message, I want the message to be sent to the person who originally created the ticket when it is closed. I have checked the documentation on something as "channel.deleted" although I'm kind of new to node.js and I don't fully understand what I am supposed to do with that since everything I have tried relating to that has not worked.